# Overloading method throws Duplicate error in Typescript

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have the next piece of code:

```
public async insert(data: iFlower | iFlower[]): Promise<iFlower> | Promise<iFlower[]> {
 await this.insert(data);
}

private async insert(data: iFlower): Promise<iFlower>{
 ....
 return data;
}

private async insert(data: iFlower[]): Promise<iFlower[]> {
 ....
 return data;
}
```

`iFlower` is:

```
export interface iFlower {
   color: string;
   number: string;
}
```

I get the following errors: 
`The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.`
`Duplicate function implementation.`
`'insert' is declared but its value is never read.`

Is it because `iFlower` is an interface?

Answer (score 1):

When you do an overload in typescript, the only thing you provide multiples of is the types. The actual implementation is just a single function. So, you'll do a series of types for the function, then one implementation which is compatible with all those types, as in:

```
private async insert(data: iFlower): Promise<iFlower>;
private async insert(data: iFlower[]): Promise<iFlower[]>;
private async insert(data: iFower | iFlower[]): Promise<iFlower> | Promise<iFlower[]> {
  // Your code here. Maybe something like:
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    ... 
    return data;
  } else {
    ... 
    return data;
  }
}
```